# Load php in background with javascript, not passing variables

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on this function that loads a php file in the background:

```
<div id="content1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

$("#content1").load("/bm_products_filter.php");
//-->
</script>
```

The original php code is this:

```
<?php require('/bm_products_filter.php');  
   ?>
```

With the original code the page works fine, with the java code it gives errors. This is because the php doesn't use the variables in the current page. I know how to pass variables to the external php but is there a way that it uses **all** the variables on the current page?

Comment: you need to rewrite the whole bm_products_filter.php script.. javascript works in a different way(there is no way to include pages in the php way).And as you are filtering / showing products you should take a look at ajax (xhr2 now).and use that to update your products from a php script.and maybe use JSON to pass your data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you wrong but you cannot load PHP files with JavaScript or JQuery.

JavaScript is client sided and has no access to the server if you want to load some data on a point of time when the template builds / is built without PHP oyu have to use an Ajax request which is also pretty simple with JQuery.

Please check out:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Err sorry, I never seen/used that. If this is a macro for an Ajax request then forget what I said sorry.

Comment: @givi i am using load but the problem is that it doesn't use the current variables in the current page , the above code is just a part of products_filter.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can rewrite the bm_products_filter.php to return a JSON output, you can use a function as below to get values returned from the php.
jsonKey1 I have used below is one of the JSON keys returned from the php.

```
function getToken() {
  var requestStr = "./bm_products_filter.php";
    $.ajax({
    url: requestStr,
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      bmProductsData = data.jsonKey1;
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.